# The resource cannot be found AJAX MVC 4 (WebApi)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
 var url = '@Url.Action("UploadFilesToDropBox", "Home")';
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: postData,

        success: function (result) {
            if (result == "Success")
                {
                AfterCreationOfFiles(selected,SelectedFormat);
            }
            }, dataType: "json",
            traditional: true

    });
```

I am using above function to call an **ActionResult**, On localhost my function runs smoothly. But when i runs it on Server, it gives me the following Error:

> The resource cannot be found.

i accidentally added WebApi, May be that is causing the Error?

Comment: What is the URL that is being produced? Is it what you expect?

Comment: What does the action method look like? Also, what about your route config?

Comment: Also you probably shouldn't be linking to your live website :)

Comment: I accidentally added WebApi.cs File, may that is causing the error??

Comment: I have no idea. But I've asked a few questions and you've answered only one. If you really want assistance then you need to give us the information to help you with.

Comment: Route config is working fine or it wont work on localhost! nd ActionResult is a POST function with parameters :S

Comment: @AnnaCastle What is the error you get?